# How to deal with correlated regressors in a multiple regression model?

Tags: regression, correlation, linear

i currently try to estimate the effect of different task parameters (IV) on neuronal activation (DV). Some predictors in my design matrix(trials x features) are moderately correlated (r~=.3) and I want to account for that because correlated predictors can lead to biased estimates of their significance.
I have read about many different approaches on how to orthogonalize predictors and stumpled upon zca-whitening. I understood that zca make the covariance matrix of the data the identity matrix by removing the covariance structure of the data. However, I could not find any example of zca whitening in the framework of multiple linear regression and I wondered why? Is that because, if I whiten the design matrix, the relation between the indpendent and dependent variable changes since whitening does not transform all variables equally (equal numbers within one feature are not equal in the whitened data anymore)? Would I need to whiten the dv and iv variable or does it in general make any sense to only whiten the design matrix? Any thoughts on that or further suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Laurie